# when exporting data using innerHTML i'm having blanks in my excel. Only selects and inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

on td class edit i only want to show the span class look when exported the selection that is currently showing in the select. Instead it's trying to render everything therefore creating blanks.

```
<tr class="proj_rec" data-id="4">
                <td class="proj_id">
                    4                    </td>
                <td>
                    Music in the stores                    </td>
                <td class="edit">
                    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                        <option value="13">Bloopers</option><option value="1">Customer Service</option><option value="2">DC</option><option value="3">Ecommerce</option><option value="4">Finance/Accounting</option><option value="5">Human Resources</option><option value="6">Inbound Logistics</option><option value="7">Information Systems</option><option value="14">Management</option><option value="8">Marketing</option><option value="9">Merchandising</option><option value="10">Property</option><option value="11">Rebuying</option><option value="12">Sales</option>                        </select>
                    <span class="look">
                        Sales                        </span>
                </td>
                <td class="edit">
                    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                        <option value="1">As is review</option><option value="2">Complete</option><option value="3">Development</option><option value="4">Implemented</option><option value="5">Not started</option><option value="6">To be design</option>                        </select>
                    <span class="look">
                        As is review                        </span>
                </td>
                <td class="edit">
                    <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                        <option value="1"> Objective</option><option value="2"> People</option><option value="3"> Process</option><option value="4"> Systems</option>                        </select>
                    <span class="look">
                         Process                        </span>
                </td>
```

[image: blank fields]

I have this back to look function:

```
function back_to_look() {
    $('td.editing ,td.edit.new').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.look').show();
        $(this).children('.touch').hide();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            $(this).addClass('edit');
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('editing')) {
            $(this).removeClass('editing');
        }
    });
}
```

Using this method:

```
<td><input type="button" id="dlink" onclick="tableToExcel('project_table', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel"></td>
            <a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();

        }
    })()
```

I tried inserting the back_to_look() before var ctx above but to no avail it didn't work. I feel I've tried everything.

I also have this myTextExtraction function that i feel might be of use but i can't properly integrate it into the tableToExcel method.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: INPUTs have values, not innerHTML.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing.  In <td class="edit"> i only need to pull <span class="look"> instead of all the option values.